# Errors when connecting oracle DB with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, oracle12c, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to use Power BI to connect with Oracle 12c Data source, I have looked for multiple solutions and followed the instruction on Microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database#installing-the-oracle-client

But I think there is something missing in work .

- **First trying to connect via Oracle Database:**

where I am installing fresh new Oracle and powerbi on the same laptop where server should be in this format "ServerName/SID" as described on documentation, so mine will be:

localhost/testdb

[image]

then adding Database user and password
[image]

and I get this  error
[image]

I have just installed Oracle 12c 64 bit on my laptop to test the connection
[image]

also I am using Power Bi 64 bit on 
[image]
also I am on windows 10 64 bit 
[image]

I have also installed "64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)" from Oracle website:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

[image]

where I have added my database to DSN using both "OraDB12Home1" and "OraClient12Home2" 
[image]

and also for both DSN I have tested the connection and it was successful 
[image]

- **Next I test connecting using ODBC OraClient12Home2:**

[image]

then inserting username and password for database 
[image]

then I get this Error 
[image]

and when I connect with OraDB12Home1 I get this error:
 [image]

I have also clear all data source connections on power bi because sometime it just display the error without sending me to next screen to enter user and password
[image]

**These are the details of tnsnames.ora** :

```
  # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: 
  C:\app\Ahmadssb\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
  # Generated by Oracle configuration tools. 

  LISTENER_TESTDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


TESTDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = testdb)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.babader.com)
    )
  )
```

I don't know what am I missing I even have exported the data from oracle as dump file and convert it as sql but it seems like this is not supported now on power bit and this is another situation.

**I need to get my database data into PowerBi the data what, am I missing and what should I do to make it connect successfully?**

---

- **Update: trying testdb on Server field:**

as suggested on comments to change **localhost/testdb** to only **testdb** (also tested in capital **TESTDB**) since it should be typed on server. But this also didn't work with me and still getting the same error check the following pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

it seems like the connection to oracle is not working, is there something I should do in oracle to make this work?

Comment: Try this in the server field: `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1512)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=testdb)));`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Cannot I get error, 'the server name cannot have more than 128 characters '

Comment: OK. Are you certain that you have the 64 bit oracle client installed?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded from the link I provided on the post, and there is a picture showing the odbc (64-bit), is there another way to check the client version i have?

Comment: This link http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Connect-To-Oracle-Database/m-p/188351#M82840 basically says to just use `TESTDB` as the server because that is the  server description in your tnsnames file.

Comment: This one http://www.redstk.com/using-power-bi-with-the-oracle-database/ also says to just use the service name from the tnsnames.ora file. That is the `TESTDB =` in your file. So try just using TESTDB

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've tested server as testdb but I get the same error  "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it seems like the connection to oracle is not working, is there something I should do in oracle to make this work?

Comment: In my experience, connection to Oracle from windows is _always_ difficult. So it's not a big suprise unfortunately. The only thing I can think of is to make sure when you do the ODBC test that you are using the 64 bit driver - run the 64 bit version of ODBCAD https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/942976/odbc-administrator-tool-displays-both-the-32-bit-and-the-64-bit-user-d

Comment: Not helping but: I share your pain. Thank you for documenting all the tedious process of trying to use Power BI Desktop with Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have formatted windows, reinstall everything from beginning and connected via ODBC and it works (yet I get the normal error **DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [07006] [Oracle][ODBC]Restricted data type attribute violation**)

but with select query for each table needed, I get it work

- downloaded [Oracle Database 12c Release 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)
- install normally
- from start menu -> Windows Administrative Tools > ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)
- in user DSN tap, follow the next pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

since connection was successful, then click "OK" to save it

next on Power BI select get source:

- select ODBC

[image]

- select the DSN name that you provided above

[image]

- now don't click on OK because it may give you an error I'll explain it below.
- click on advanced option
- type a SELECT query for specific table and click OK
  [image]
- then it'll display the table data preview, click load 
  [image]
- congratulation, you are done 
  [image]

in case you didn't type a select query and clicked OK 
then  you added your username and password

[image]

- it'll connect and display list of tables, but you may end up with this error (the provided solution on the internet was the above one ):

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/ODBC-Connection-error-07006/td-p/278165

[image]

that's  how i get it to connect finally, still i have small issue not related to this topic I put it on another question,
but hopefully this answer will help others to connect

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to get PowerBI to work with the Oracle driver by uninstalling the PowerBI from the Microsoft Store and downloading the msi file from the advanced download options on https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/desktop/.  I suspect it's some security restriction with a store app that prevents using the Oracle libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I also made the experience that the [Connect via Oracle Database description by MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database#installing-the-oracle-client) is not working. However, I could establish a connections via the "Oracle Database" option (i.e. `Get Data > Oracle Database > Server`), without using ODBC, by entering the credentials in the following format:

`[HOSTNAME]:[PORT]/[SERVICE_NAME]`

so e.g.:

```
localhost:1521/myservice.com
```

Answer (score 0):

It follows the same connection architecture as SQL Plus, so the Server field in Power BI should contain whatever follows the @ sign in your successful SQL Plus test.

So I would try **TESTDB** in the Server field when making an Oracle connection from Power BI, not **localhost/testdb**.  If that works I presume you could ignore ODBC.

Comment: it is not working as well check my update on the post, still getting the same error!

Comment: it seems like the connection to oracle is not working, is there something I should do in oracle to make this work?

Comment: I would concentrate on testing the connection using 64-bit sqlplus.exe and tnsping.exe. Launch them from the BIN folder under the 64-bit install tree.  When those work, use the same settings for Power BI.

Comment: Dont beat yourself up, the oracle client install & config are a nightmare.